# Можно ли научиться грамотному письму без применения правил?

Tags: методика

Существует методическая школа Романовых "Правилам - нет", вот ее основные тезисы:

1) Грамматические правила не используются.

2) Традиционные понятия «части речи» и «части слова» (морфемы) отсутствуют. Под запретом находятся понятия: «словарное слово», «исключение», «раздельное» написание и так далее.

3) Множество системных ошибок обусловлены как раз-таки именно попытками применения правил традиционной орфографии и пунктуации.

4) Учить и применять по ходу письма грамматические правила просто бессмысленно. И т.д.

[Без правил! Введение в практическую грамотность | romanova-school.ru](http://romanova-school.ru/page/mat1)

По моему мнению, **человека труднее научить говорить**, чем писать. **Грамматика в речи — это главное**. Она может усваиваться на интуитивном уровне при большом опыте общения, она корректируется на письме, когда человек учиться составлять **стилистически** грамотные тексты. Грамматика, структура, стилистика  —  основа всего, если это освоено, то скорректировать правильность письма (по правилам!)  не так уж трудно (письмо — это же всего лишь запись уже грамотно составленного текста).

А что люди получат в этой школе? Как можно говорить о владении языком, **если пользователь "на автомате" научился записывать диктанты, и это всё его умение?**  Стоит ли доверять таким методикам?

**Дополнение (немного об истории вопроса)**

В 20-30-х годах XX века велась очень оживленная дискуссия о методах обучения грамотному письму. Существовало две школы: грамматики и антиграмматики. Первые считали грамматику основой для составления правил, вторые предпочитали интуитивное письмо, связывая его с необходимостью  больше писать, чем заниматься теорией. Но вот школа Романовых и переписывание также отвергает, я бы определила их методику как погружение в какой-то "орфографический транс", который они называют автоматическим письмом. Возможно, их методика близка к нейропсихологическим методам обучения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что сайт не предназначен для выяснения мнений и вопросов, напрямую не связанных с разделами языкознания.

Comment: Здесь нельзя обсуждать методики обучения языку? Тогда закройте  все вопросы этой тематики (Как научится грамотно писать? Какие посоветуете учебники? И т.д.).

Comment: На сайте уже было задано несколько вопросов, связанных с методологией. Действующие правила сайта не позволяют точно определить их статус, в связи с чем я предлагаю вам создать соответствующий вопрос на Мете с целью прояснить его. Я переоткрою ваш текущий вопрос — давайте выясним мнение других участников.

Comment: Думаю, что не стоит напрягаться и определять статус. Напишите в Справке: Вопросы, связанные с методологией изучения языка, не допускаются.

Comment: Мы не можем написать это в Справке без поддержки сообщества, поэтому я и сделал вам предложение определить статус подобных вопросов с помощью вопроса на Мете. Напоминаю, что ресурс управляется сообществом.

Comment: @Aer На вопросы просто связанные с методологией никто не собирался покушаться только потому, что они такие есть. И вряд ли кто это поддержит. Вопрос надо закрыть по простой причине, которую вы и обозначили. Нет и не будет объективно верного ответа. Эта-то причина ясно прописана... А тут еще такая заведомо провокативная тема...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут важно, как эта методика расположена во времени. Иногда нужно заучивать правила орфографии и грамматики при работе с языком, иногда нужно что-то другое - например, изучение качественных художественных текстов. В первом классе точно морфемы и части речи не нужны и даже вредны. Годам к 12 изучение грамматики родного языка становится необходимым - для пробуждения осознанного отношения к учёбе вообще (говорит нам, в частности, Л.С.Выготский в своей работе "Мышление и речь").

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение.  Интересно то, что эта методика предлагается достаточно взрослым людям  (не в школе, разумеется),  и она рассчитана на активный интерес со стороны пользователей. Всем хочется стать грамотными, причем быстро, не напрягаясь, по каким-то особым методам. Я согласна, что в начальной школе больше внимания нужно уделять развитию интуитивного письма, а теории давать поменьше и на практических примерах. Но  потом без знания грамматики не обойтись. Объём этих знаний невелик, но владеть ими надо в совершенстве,  потому что это форма, куда вы вкладываете содержание ваших мыслей.

Answer (score -1):

Можно! И мой пример - другим наука!

Не изучала постулаты школы Романовых, может, я повторю их ценную мысль, но к ней я пришла сама:

вместо чудовищных многокилометровых правил, которые, как доказала практика, всё одно не усваиваются (и тому пример - наш сайт, где каждый третий, если не второй, пишет с ошибками), следует учиться языку

РАБОТОЙ НАД ОШИБКАМИ.

Вот ляпнул брак, тебя в него фейсом ткнули, - ога, хозяйке на заметку! Типо я больше так не буду.

Зачем изучать то, где ты (я, он, она, они) и не думаешь ошибаться?

Comment: Галина, а как насчет  грамматики? Ведь эти Романовы все грамматические термины предлагают забыть, морфемы там, части речи, члены предложения, наверное.  Неужели можно без них обойтись?! Я "многокилометровые правила" тоже не приветствую, но вот грамматику ценю как нечто совершенно необходимое.

Comment: Мне, чтобы узнать, что такое "грамматика", нужно лезть в толковый словарь! Грамматическими терминами не пользуюсь (если не берусь за ответ по русскому языку) вкупе с "морфемами там, частями речи, членами предложения". Я очень много лучших ответов получала по русскому на мэйловских "Ответах" и на "Большом Вопросе", ну да я гуглить умею! На што нам Гугл даден?! О_о